# error in DECLARE variable mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, declare

this is my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `proximo_pago` BEFORE INSERT ON `pago`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 declare num_orden integer;

select max(orden) from pago  where lote=NEW.lote into num_orden;
if(num_orden is NULL)
then 
    set NEW.orden=1;
 else
 set NEW.orden=num_orden+1;
 end if;
END
```

and the ERROR

SQL query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `proximo_pago` BEFORE INSERT ON `pago`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  declare num_orden integer;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

I've tried to use DELIMITER but it isn´t works, please help me , thanks

Comment: I can't see any error except, perhaps, a missing semicolon after last `END`. See this demo, it uses your trigger and works perfectly fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcd1f/1 Copy the trigger from this demo, uncomment `delimiter` commands at the beginning and at the end of the code, and it should compile, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based only on the necessity of your question which is declaration of the variable.. if the Delimiter doesn't do the trick maybe its an error in your syntax because you didn't SET your     SELECT query in a variable. try this first.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
TRIGGER `proximo_pago` BEFORE INSERT 
on `pago`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE num_orden int;

SET num_orden = select max(orden) from pago  where lote=NEW.lote;
if(num_orden is NULL)
then 
set NEW.orden=1;
else
set NEW.orden=num_orden+1;
end if;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```